# Regex: Replace first comma of every line with tab

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to Replace first comma of every line with a tab so that the values will align.
I have been trying but below regex I have been testing is not leading me to the correct way.

```
$data -replace "^[^,]*\,{1}","`t`t`t"
$data -replace ",(.*){1}","`t`t"

Raw: 
First Name Then Last,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported

Another Long Name,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,[______],[______],[______]

Short Name,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,[______],[______],[______]

Name Another Name Last,Exported,Porgress,[______],[______],[______],[______],[______]


Needed Output:
First Name Then Last,       Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported

Another Long Name,          Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,[______],[______],[______]

Short Name,Exported,        Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,[______],[______],[______]

Name Another Name Last,     Exported,Porgress,[______],[______],[______],[______],[______]
```

[image: Needed Output]
[image: Raw File]

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65028380/3832970) below help?

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the first comma with a tab using

```
$data -replace '^([^,]*),', "`$1`t"
```

Here, `^([^,]*),` matches start of string, then captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `,` and then a comma, and replaced with Group 1 backreference  (`$1`) and the tab char.

Alternatively, use a lookbehind:

```
$data -replace "(?<=^[^,]*),", "`t"
```

Here, `(?<=^[^,]*),` matches a `,` that is immediately preceded with any 0+ non-comma chars from the start of string.

[image]

If you want to insert a tab char after the comma that has six more commas after it, you can use

```
$data = 'First Name Then Last, Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported'
$data -replace ',\s*(?=(?:[^,]*,){6}[^,]*$)', "`$&`t"
# => First Name Then Last,   Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported
```

Here, `,\s*(?=(?:[^,]*,){6}[^,]*$)` matches a `,`, then zero or more whitespaces that are followed with six occurrences of 0+ non-comma chars followed with a comma and then any zero or more chars other than a comma till  the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

If `$data` is already an array of strings (lines), then I would use `-split` and `join` for this:

```
$data | ForEach-Object { ($_ -split ',', 2) -join "`t" }
```